# how to copy an array to clipboard in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this simple function in which i try to pass an array to the clipboard in order to paste in in excel later on

```
hiddenInputOnCopyHandler = ev => {    
    ev.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', ev.currentTarget.value.split(','));
    ev.preventDefault();
  };
```

but i'm getting a string instead, i guess because the type passed in the setData is 'text/plain'
but i couldn't find better in [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData)

now the problem is that when it's pasted in excel , the whole serialized array will take only one cell
[image]

Comment: Do you want the result in the clipboard to look like the array elements concatnated together or something like ["a","b","c"]?

Comment: yes i want it an array like ["a","b","c"]

Comment: you should try tab `\t` instead of comma `,`, ([reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/default-delimiter/15dc47c9-bbea-4b09-ac17-d415de927a73)) `ev.currentTarget.value.split(',').join('\t')`

Comment: thanks @hgb123, please rewrite your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try tab `\t` instead of comma `,` ([reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/default-delimiter/15dc47c9-bbea-4b09-ac17-d415de927a73))

```
ev.currentTarget.value.split(',').join('\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), you should fire a `copy` command to copy the selection to clipboard. Also you should check for browser compatibility.

Also `currentTarget.value` gives undefined so you should use `textContent` instead.

When you click on paragraph, then it fires the `copy` command in `copyAction` function and then `eventListener` with `copy` event executes the `hiddenInputonCopyHandler` function.

```
function init(){

   let el = document.getElementById("CpToClip");
    el.addEventListener('click',copyAction);
    
    el.addEventListener('copy', hiddenInputOnCopyHandler);
    
}

function copyAction(){
   document.execCommand('copy');  
}

hiddenInputOnCopyHandler = ev => {
    let copiedVal = ev.currentTarget.textContent.trim().split(',').join('\t');
    
    console.log(copiedVal);// "HHHhhh" "mkjf" "Tendue" "Bonne" "10-07-2020" "khgkg@kjk.od"    
    
    ev.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copiedVal);
    ev.preventDefault();
}


addEventListener('load',init);
```

Html

```
<p id="CpToClip">
   HHHhhh,mkjf,Tendue,Bonne,10-07-2020,khgkg@kjk.od
</p>
```

Check my solution and let me know.

Comment: i did call document.execCommand('copy');  but it didn't update the clipboard content and i had to add that paste handler that i mentionned in my question to re-do it there (and it finally worked)..

Comment: @Bardelman As you can see from my code, you should click the `p` tag in order to copy the content. You can modify it as you wish, check my updated answer.